# What was the movie name with a parasitic creature?

Tags: story-identification, horror, alien-invasion

- Creature could be reproduced from a partial tissue
- It also attacked a dog to grow (it was either opening or closing of the movie)
- It also attacked a homeless person in a tunnel or something Then passed to multiple hosts, leaving old hosts in dead or vegetable states.
- Some kind of energy blaster was used to destroyed it but it was in todays earth
- The Creature was grosser than the Xenomorph alien but less capable
- The Creature was using living entities as living sources or energy sources or something and it was jumping to another host by a kiss(?) Maybe that wasn't a kiss but an exorcism-style projectile vomit? I really can't remember.
- Something like a blend of '**The Thing**' and '**Alien<sup>3</sup>**'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [The Hidden](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/) from 1987. There's a scene where a [dog gets taken over](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47eGq1hyMRI) by an alien parasite that jumps hosts through oral contact.